# Search and Replace the string in same file and count the number replaced

Tags: perl

I am just trying to search a string "Kumar" and replacing that string with Mahi. But output is not coming . can any body point me where i am doing mistake.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

open(my $fh, "+>","test.txt") || die "File not found";
my @lines = <$fh>;

my @newlines;
my $count;
foreach my $line(@lines) {
   if($line =~/Kumar/i){   
   $line =~ s/Kumar/Mahi/ig;
   print $fh $line;
   #push(@newlines,$line);
   $count++;
   }
}

#print $fh @newlines;
close($fh);
```

Txt file:

```
Kumar Yadav vivek Kumar Yadav
qualcomm Kumar Yadav tarun Kumar sumit
adbd Kumar shahi Kumar sinha
```

Comment: You are aware that you only print those lines with Kumar in them, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open($fh, "<", "file.txt") or die "cannot open file:$!\n";
while( my $line = <$fh>){
   $line =~ s/Kumar/Mahi/;
   print $line ."\n";
}
close($fh);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I am just trying to search a string "Kumar" and replacing that string with Mahi

IF this is only what you need, then why not use a simple one-liner?...

```
$ cat test.txt 
line1
Kumar
Line2
Kumar

$ perl -i -p -e 's/Kumar/Mahi/g' test.txt 

$ cat test.txt 
line1
Mahi
Line2
Mahi
```

**UPDATE:** Question title and the problem statement has been drastically changed during the lifecycle of this post. So, this answer may not provide the correct solution anymore.

Comment: Ha! I'll break your perfect 3000 rep by giving +1! Muhahahahaha.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$^I = "";
@ARGV = ("test.txt");

while (my $line = readline()) {

   print $line if $line =~ s/Kumar/Mahi/ig;
}
```

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$%5EI)

> - $^I
>
> The current value of the inplace-edit extension. Use undef to disable inplace editing.
> Mnemonic: value of -i switch.

Comment: May be you should an explanation of `$^I` for everyone to understand. AFAIK, it is perl command line equivalent of `-i`.

Comment: Also this answer does not write the lines back into a truncated test.txt and prints all lines except for just those that had kumar in them.

Comment: @DeVadder on which perl version did you try?

Comment: @mpapec ActivePerl-5.16 But i believe i understand why you ask, `$^I` works, my comment is formulated abysmally. What i mean is, the output file still contains all lines that did not have Kumar in them. While the Op only keeps those lines around and truncates the rest. Then again the Op truncated a lot more than advisable (as in before reading) so it is not clear whether the op actually only wanted to replace Kumar or if getting rid of all other lines was intentionally.

Comment: @DeVadder check update. That is the problem with some questions where code doesn't follow problem description.

Answer (score 1):

```
open(my $fh, "+>","test.txt")
```

This truncates the file while opening. So there is nothing to read when you come to the reading part.
You should probably open it with `<` first, read it, close it and then open it with `>` for writing.

Answer (score 0):

+> means truncate the file first, and then start reading. eventually you are getting nothing from the file.

+< means read the file and update as well. but new text will be placed at the end of the file.

So I guess for your purpose, you'll require two separate file handler for read and write operation. A detail about the file I/O can be found from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_files.htm).